# Multiply a value in echo

Tags: php

I have an API wherein users can request the price of the item.
When the price is echoed, the server response is as below,

```
PRICE:384.00
```

I want to multiply only the number part with some constant. For eg. if I want to double the price of it how would I do it?

Doing like this isn’t helping me,

```
case 'getPrice':
     $price = $_GET['getPrice'];
     echo $price*2;
```

I just get a response as `0PRICE:384.00` instead I want it to display `PRICE:768.00`
I searched other answers but they didn't have the `PRICE` part in the response.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

If the string you get back is `PRICE:384.00`, and you want to modify `384.00`, you first need to extract that part.

```
$string = $_GET['getPrice']; // PRICE:384.00
$parts = explode(":", $string);

$newPrice = $parts[1] * 2; // Multiply the second value, which is 384.00
echo $parts[0].":".$newPrice;
```

Comment: I tried this but I get :0PRICE:384.00. What actually is happening is I am parsing a response from another server and trying to multiply the second part, hope I am clear.

Comment: Then you're doing something else that we can't see, see this demo: https://3v4l.org/Qgi4b

Comment: Oh, yeah it is working. What I know is that number keeps changing. Think it as if I am a dropshipper. I want to sell a product, when the manufacturer changes the prices, I need t change this value too, so I would like to do it automatically rather than doing it manually. Is this possible sir?

Comment: Yes it is possible, the manufacturer of the product needs to provide you a Web Service with API in which you will consume in your application. The API will direct you on how to implement the functionality to accomplish the task